# Find $\gcd(5n+3,3n+2)$, $n\in \Bbb{Z}, n\ge 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $\gcd(5n+3,3n+2)$, $n\in \Bbb{Z}, n\ge 1$. I don't know where to start. First two questions were: a. Prove $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$. b. Prove $\gcd(ab+c,a)=\gcd(c,a)$. Maybe it has something to do with it. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: (b) will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, if $a>b$, then $\gcd (a,b) = \gcd (b, a-b)$. Then $\gcd (5n+3,3n+2) = \gcd (3n+2,2n+1) = \gcd (2n+1,n+1) = \gcd (n+1,n) = \gcd (n,1) = 1$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,a−b)$?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel: The proof is extremely simple, but do you expect us to do all the homework for you? It wouldn't be fair, would it? Just try to prove it, it's extremely simple.

Comment: Not at all. You pointed it out just as if it were the most trivial thing, which it weren't, so I have just had it checked.

Comment: Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then $d|a$ and $d|b$, so $d|a-b$, so $d|\gcd(b, a-b)$. Assume that $d'|\gcd(b,a-b)$ and $d'>d$. Then $d'|a$ and $d'|a-b$, so $d'|b$, so $d'| \gcd(a,b)=d$, which is impossible because $d'>d$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Observe that $$5(3n+2)-3(5n+3)=1$$

The idea is to eliminate $n$ and to find a constant

and use the fact that $(a,b)|(ax+by)$ where $x,y$ are integers

Comment: Doesn't it mean the $gcd=1$? 
Once I get rid of $n$, I don't have what to work with... Just a number...

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel, It means that the GCD divides $-1\implies$ GCD =?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why don't you write $5(3n+2)-3(5n+3)=1?$

Comment: @Fermat, Ya, acceptably more readable